# What is "query writer, new query in SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express

Using: SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008, C# website asp.net

Okay, I have always used SQL Server 2005 Express and its Management Studio as a host and a design interface to create tables from design view only.

All the queries, transaction, retrieval and anything needed during run time of the website is done using Visual Studio 2008 sql "connection open, then form command statement, and execute reader etc its all done using Visual Studio 08 c#"

So I was wondering that there is a query writer thing in SQL Server Management Studio Express.

What is it for ?

- can it be used in place of vs08 c# queries?
- how to call it from web sites c#?
- can it use for variables queries like `where id = @input` etc

Please provide links to tutorials which explain how to use SQL Server studio and Visual Studio 2008 together I searched the net but cannot find the answer

Comment: kindly answer with down voting, atleast that would give me an idea of how unclear and not useful the question is

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted - but I must admit: I do not understand what you're asking. Maybe you need to rephrase your question? Provide a sample of what you're doing and what you want to do in the future?

Comment: Maybe you were down voted because your question is hard to understand. Anyway check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query writer to write queries that you only want to use right then, instead of setting up a web site to run queries over and over again. You can also use it to create something called stored procedures, which you can then call from your web site. However, if you want, you can do both of those things with Visual Studio, I believe. Stored procedures can accept input variables, and are very useful that way. Personally, I like them. Not everyone does. If you call them from C# with a Command object, you probably need to change the .CommandType property of the object to StoredProcedure.